# Specifying latest revision of a particular branch with bower

Tags: bower

I want to specify the latest revision of a particular branch as a dependency. Specifically, I'd like to use Bootstrap v3.0 before it is released.

What is the best way to specify that as a dependency in bower?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install latest (untagged) state of a repo using bower?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949173/how-to-install-latest-untagged-state-of-a-repo-using-bower)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to use the `#`, [appended to the component name](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/771):

```
bower install bootstrap#version3-branch-name
```

And as you might expect, if you add `--save-dev` to that, then it will add to your `bower.json` file:

```
"bootstrap": "version3-branch-name"
```

Comment: This works and should be upvoted. Another example `"ckeditor": "#basic/latest"` for https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases

Comment: Does this automatically pull new changes from the same branch on a re-run of bower install?

Comment: No, so that's why is recommended to use a commit SHA instead.

Answer (score 43):

You can specify the commit SHA instead of a version:

```
bower install bootstrap#37d0a30589
```

*Note that specifying a branch in production or reusable modules is bad practice as it's a moving target and will eventually break something. Discussion about it [here](https://github.com/twitter/bower/issues/107).*

Comment: what's the status on this?

Comment: Can we use a `<library>#<branch_name>`?

Answer (score 21):

Until bower gets the ability to [target a specific commit](https://github.com/twitter/bower/issues/275) as @Sindre noted, I am taking advantage of bower's ability to target arbitrary zip files. I specified github's zip of bootstrap's 3.0 branch in my component.json:

`"bootstrap": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/3.0.0-wip.zip"`

I understand this is bad practice to target a branch (rather than a specific commit), but this works for me for now as a stopgap.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a bad practice per se, it depends on how you are using it.

Comment: Bower now allows you to target a specific commit