# How to install latest (untagged) state of a repo using bower?

Tags: bower

I have a *very* small repo in which I do all dev work in the master branch and use tags as "stable" points in history.

I guess by default Bower seems to fetch the latest **tagged** version of a repo. I'm trying to get the most recent commit in the master branch.

I've tried running all these, in every conceivable order:

```
bower cache-clean mypackage
bower install mypackage --force-latest
bower install mypackage --force --force-latest
bower install mypackage --force
```

I've also tried adding `latest` to my bower.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mypackage": "latest"
}
```

And then running:

```
bower update mypackage
```

No matter what it seems to always get the latest tagged state.

How do I get the latest, most up-to-date, untagged state of the project?

Comment: Full documentation https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Specify a git commit SHA instead of a version:

```
bower install '<git-url>#<git-commit-sha>'
```

Example:

```
bower install 'git://github.com/yeoman/stringify-object.git#d2895fb97d'
```

You can also specify a branch instead of a SHA, but that's generally not recommended unless it's in development and you control all the parts.

Comment: Ya, I read through all the discussion about all that in the GH issue tracker last night and installed bower#0.9.3-rc0. You are correct sir. Thanks!

Comment: By now, you can also just use `<git-url>#<branch-name>` instead of adding a SHA-ID. So you can also use `<git-url>#master` to track the master branch.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my private repository though. I am trying to specify the commit id. It returns an error " fatal: reference is not a tree:". Looks like it's trying to find the revision in container's git repo.

Comment: I'm getting the fatal: reference is not a tree as well. Quite annoying.

Comment: how do you force the install of an older version in the package.json if you already have a newer one?

Answer (score 112):

Yes, you can point to the git url, or use name/repo shorthand (for github repos):

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "bower-test",
  "dependencies": {
    "dpm": "git@github.com:okfn/dpm.git",
    "docker-nmpjs": "terinjokes/docker-npmjs"
  }
}
```

More in the [docs](http://bower.io/#install-packages)

As @roi noted in the comments, you can use the `--save` flag to automatically add dependencies to `bower.json`, e.g. `bower install terinjokes/docker-npmjs --save`

Comment: and is selecting a version possible?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Yes, you can follow the ``<package>#<revision>.`` format listed in the docs. So, to use the latest version of jQuery in the "master" branch, you would do: ``git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git#master`` or ``jquery/jquery#master`` for short.

Comment: i would say you'll have better luck using the cli to get it into your bower.json..... bower install terinjokes/docker-npmjs --save

Comment: We can also mention the releases / tags using # symbol like so - `xyz-components": "git@github.sample.com:username/reponame.git#0.4.5`

Answer (score 32):

You can install a branch in Bower > 1.0.0:

```
bower install xxx#foo-branch
```

More details at https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/107#issuecomment-22352689.

Comment: To clarify for the `master` branch you would type `xxx#master`, NOT `xxx#master-branch`.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using a bower.json file you specify the latest version of a branch with a line in either the dependencies or devDependencies as appropriate for your project configuration:

```
"angular-bootstrap": "git@github.com:angular-ui/bootstrap.git#bootstrap3",
```

Then when you run `bower install` the latest version of that branch is installed.  That would be branch `bootstrap3` of `angular-ui` in this example.

Comment: This works locally but will fail on Heroku. You should use the `git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap.git#bootstrap3` instead.

Answer (score 15):

```
bower install --save package-name#master
```

adds this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "package-name": "master"
}
```

Answer (score 10):

using bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery.slimscroll": "latest",
    "jQuery": "1.11",
    "fullPage.js": "git@github.com:overbyte/fullPage.js.git#1d6bbac3d4c3b1d3d7d4096cdbcabd1c3914393f",
}
```

where

```
"[library name - in this case a forked version of fullpage.js]" : "[from git clone box in github][#commit number if required - without this you will get latest tagged version]"
```