# How to get Bower to point to the latest version?

Tags: bower

If you search for [mjolnic](http://bower.io/search/?q=mjolnic) on Bower, you'll see there's a mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker repo. The repo has a bower.json pointing to v2.0.0-rc, but when you `bower install mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker`, you get a much older version.

How can I make it so bower defaults to installing the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"dependencies": {
    "mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker": "latest"
}
```

into your bower json

more information here : [How to install latest (untagged) state of a repo using bower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949173/how-to-install-latest-untagged-state-of-a-repo-using-bower)