# Installing a forked package with bower

Tags: bower, bower-install

I forked a Github repository and then commited after some customization, building and changing it's `bower.json` name and url. Now when I want to install it with bower like this:

```
bower install https://github.com/myUserName/originlRepoName.git
```

the original one is installed!
How can I install my forked version!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to properly register a github fork with Bower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104623/how-to-properly-register-a-github-fork-with-bower)