# Why doesn't bower install <gitRepoAddress> install what I see on the git repo?

Tags: git, github, bower

I am trying to use bower to install https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map but using `bower install` `angular-ui-map` does not produce what I see in the git repo. In my understanding this is because the version has to be tagged as the latest (or something there abouts) so I am not getting what I expect.

I thought using `bower install git@github.com:angular-ui/ui-map.git` would definitely get me what I saw on github but this is not the case.

So why doesn't either of these commands get me what I see in the git repo? Is something out of date? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest (untagged) state of a repo using bower?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949173/how-to-install-latest-untagged-state-of-a-repo-using-bower)