# How to use a pull request with bower?

Tags: angularjs, bower

Sorry if I may have a bad title.
This is the situation:

The angular library [angular-animate](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate) in its latest version, doesn't seem to have fixed an IE bug.

The problem is that in IE I get this error in the console:

```
Unable to get property 'toFixed' of undefined or null reference in ng-animate.js
```

A few resources say the problem can be solved by having angular and angular-animate at the same version.
And this is what I did. But I still see the error in the console.

Looking at the code in angular-animate.js, I can see that the error happens at this row:

```
var elapsedTime = parseFloat(ev.elapsedTime.toFixed(ELAPSED_TIME_MAX_DECIMAL_PLACES));
```

So I saw a merge request done by somebody here: [angular.js/pull/15405](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/15405/commits/1dd33120cdd2d66d24d04681f473d010bf717594)

Where the row above is replaced by this:

```
var elapsedTime = ev && ev.elapsedTime ? parseFloat(ev.elapsedTime.toFixed(ELAPSED_TIME_MAX_DECIMAL_PLACES)) : maxDuration;
```

When changing this manually, I see the error disappear in IE. But how can I tell bower to fetch just this commit from github, as it resolves the issue?
I don't want to make a bower install and then go inside the downloaded bower components and manually change that file.

Please note that Im using bower.json to specify dependencies and versions.
So I would need to understand what to put inside the bower.json for getting the right version for angular-animate.
However, I must confess that I am a little bit confused.
What I found here: [angular.js/pull/15405](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/15405/commits/1dd33120cdd2d66d24d04681f473d010bf717594)
is NOT for angular-animate, but for angular.js. So I am a little bit lost, as I thought that would be repo for angular-animate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949173/how-to-install-latest-untagged-state-of-a-repo-using-bower

Answer (score 2):

Install the fork that you want to use.

```
bower install 'git://github.com/shaiatias/angular.js.git'
```